# MapQuest how to hide map and only show overlay?

Tags: java, android, mapquest

I wish one of you ever use this Map library named MapQuest.
for save performance and network access, I want to hide map and only show overlay.
But I don't find any clues how to do it.

How to hide map and only show overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to hide the map and create a very basic overlay with something like this.

```
ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapOverlay);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
for (Overlay overlay: mapView.getOverlays()) {
  overlay.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
}
v.setImageBitmap(bmp);
mapView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```